# Python Container exiting without error after a few operations - Docker for Windows

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have a docker container running a bunch of python scripts. I am using HyperV as backend virtualization engine on Docker and running Docker for Windows.

The container builds just fine but when I start the container with:

```
docker run --memory 10240mb -it container_name
```

It runs the few initial operations from the file, prints out the results and then exits without an error. When I run:

```
docker logs --tail=50 container_id
```

I see just the print outs as when I ran docker run, funnily enough the moment it exists is pretty random operation wise (it might exit after first 2 ops or sometimes 1 op) but it usually ends the same time, as if there was a timer letting it run only for 5 minutes minutes for example. The script runs fine on a different machine running VirtualBox and Docker-Machine.

Comment: Dockerfile? your `bunch of python scripts`? Errors / Logs?
please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: These details @Ammar are irrelevant and they would pollute the description. As mentioned the image is building and executing just fine so dockerfile is not the issue, python scripts executing are the same simple script from scikit-learn which run just fine locally and also in the container 1-2 times before the container exits, as well as on a different machine running virtualbox as the backend vm. As mentioned also there is nothing in the logs. The container should perform 10 operations and exit and it exits without reason after 1-2 after a certain time period.

Comment: Try running without `--memory 10240mb`

Comment: @VinDev I did previously with the same result, this was added because I thought it might be memory issues inside the container

Comment: Try: `docker run -ti container_name bash` this will start the container with a shell session inside the container, try and run the python scripts from the shell which may give you more details on what is happening

Comment: @VinDev I tried that, the logs are the same, except at the end I get "Killed" from bash output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the docker icon in the system tray

Click on advanced

increase the memory settings to what you need, if you're not sure try setting it somewhere close to the middle depending on your system. You might go ahead and increase the CPU setting as well if you can.

Save your changes Docker will restart
Once that's done you should be able to run your app run it without the --memory option

Comment: Around 4GB of memory allocation or more is ideal

Comment: Knowing how much memory depends on a lot of things so I would start as high as possible to confirm this is the issue (almost sure it is OOM issue) and get it working, you can turn it back down later if you need to

Comment: Thanks. I upped the memory to 8 gigs and it started working fine, I am surprised there was no output from the python console suggesting it OOM since locally and on jupyter I just get the errors.